# how to perform setTimeout function and scroll to bottom at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a script for chatting between two users. I want the scroll bar go to bottom(as done by most chatting apps) and when the users entered a new text again the scroll bar remain to the bottom most positon. But also want to refresh the chat box every .5 ms so that it takes place in real time for both the chatting users.

```
        <script>
var currentID = null;
var chatTimer = null;

function fetch_data() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#live_data').html(data);
      //fetch_chat();
    }
  });
}

function fetchChat() { // 30% of chance of having new message
    if (Math.random() <= 0.3) {
        $("#messages").append("<div>" + "Random message " + Math.random() + "</div>");

        // Scroll to bottom if you are at bottom, with tolerance of 50px
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50) {
            scrollToBottom();
        }
    }
}
function sendMessage(txt) {
    $("#messages").append("<div>" + txt + "</div>");
        $.post('insert_chat.php', {
            id: currentID,
            msg: txt
            }, function(data) {

            });
    scrollToBottom();
}

function scrollToBottom() {
    $(window).scrollTop(1e10); // Lazy hack
}

setInterval(function() {
    fetchChat();
}, 500);

function fetch_chat() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "fetch_chat.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: currentID
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#messages").show();
      $('#messages').html(data);
      $("div.area").show();
      //chatTimer = setTimeout(fetch_chat, 500); //request the chat again in 2 seconds time
      // $("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
      // return false;
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50) {
            scrollToBottom();
    }
}
  });
}



$(document).ready(function() {
 fetch_data();
  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
    currentID = $(this).data("id1");
    //immediately fetch chat for the new ID, and clear any waiting fetch timer that might be pending
   // clearTimeout(chatTimer);
    fetch_chat(); 
  });

$("#text").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        sendMessage($("#text").val());
        $("#text").val("");
    }
})

  //this will also trigger the first fetch_chat once it completes
});
</script>
```

here's the script. I want the scroll bar to be at the bottom but when user wnat to scroll up for previous messages then it should also works,which in my doesnt coz I have put it in the fetch_chat(). Plz help me to get me the desired output.

Comment: But also want to refresh the chat box every .5 ms so that it takes place in real time .....  why just 5 minutes

Comment: I guess OP means milliseconds. But in the code it's 500ms, so rather 0.5 seconds.

Comment: @connum yes u r right.

Comment: for scroll actions you actually have to wait for the full load event that even triggers `window.onload`. `$(document).ready` actually is not good enough for scrolling. if your chat is finished loading before the page loaded completely you can pretty much run into initial scrolling problems.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
function fetchChat() { // 30% of chance of having new message
    if (Math.random() <= 0.3) {
        $("#messages").append("<div>" + "Random message " + Math.random() + "</div>");
        
        // Scroll to bottom if you are at bottom, with tolerance of 50px
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50) {
            scrollToBottom();
        }
    }
}

function sendMessage(txt) {
    $("#messages").append("<div>" + txt + "</div>");
    scrollToBottom();
}

function scrollToBottom() {
    $(window).scrollTop(1e10); // Lazy hack
}

setInterval(function() {
    fetchChat();
}, 500);

$("#input").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        sendMessage($("#input").val());
        $("#input").val("");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messages"></div>
<input id="input" type="text"/>
```

Comment: I just recheck and realise I misunderstand your question, I am rewriting the solution

Comment: Edited the answer, you can run the code and check if it is what you want

Comment: I followed ur given code and editted the script . plz go through it once. The scroll bar is not sticking to the bottom as it did in ur code snippet.
plz tell me where i m goin wrong